# не могу передать id из <select> React

Tags: reactjs

```
const Menu = ()=>{

    const [item, setItem]=useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('index')))

    const onStatusChange =(id,e)=>{
        console.log(id)
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <select className='menu' defaultValue={item.status} onChange={(e)=>onStatusChange(item.id, e)}>
            {item.map((item, index) => (
                    <option  key={index}> {item.item}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    )
}
```

в консоле вместо id undefined, а вот item приходит

Comment: Не понятно что же у тебя в том `item`... Ты используешь его как массив `item.map()` и как объект `item.status`, `item.id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы получить **id**, его необходимо записать в атрибуте тега **option**

```
const Menu = () => {

  const [item, setItem] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('index')))

  const onStatusChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].text)
  }

  return (
    <select className='menu' defaultValue={item.status} onChange={onStatusChange}>
      {item.map((item, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={item.id}>{item.item}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}
```

Использование `onChange={(e)=>onStatusChange(item.id, e)}` неправильно, т.к. **item** это массив и у него нет свойства **id**